# Add $_POST['url'] to body of email Pear package?

Tags: php, email, pear

I need my php script to email me some variables which is parsed to it.

I receive the email properly when any text is passed:

```html
mypage.php?url=hello
```

But I do not receive the email if an url is passed:

```html
mypage.php?url=http://www.google.com
```

I searched for hours but didn't found any way to do it.

This is the php script:

```html
<?php
// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";


$name = $_POST['name'];
$url = $_POST['url'];



$from = '<noreply@website.com>';
$to = '<me@gmail.com>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = '


Name: '.$name.'
The url is: '.$url.'


';

            
$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);



$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'mail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password'
    ));


$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<h1>Message successfully sent!</h1>');
}

?>
```

When an actual url is parsed, I don't recive the email but also no error is shown.

Comment: Try the [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function in php around the URL. Perhaps PEAR have issues escaping it.

Comment: store url in variable then assign in url

Comment: @Xorifelse Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also, its good to turn on error reporting while developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Xorifelse said, I used addslashes function and it worked. I  got the email properly with the url in it.

Below is the working script:

```html
<?php
// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";


$name = $_POST['name'];
$url = $_POST['url'];



$from = '<noreply@website.com>';
$to = '<me@gmail.com>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = '


Name: '.addslashes($name).'
The url is: '.addslashes($url).'


';

            
$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);



$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'mail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password'
    ));


$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<h1>Message successfully sent!</h1>');
}

?>
```

Comment: Just saying, it was a wild guess. I personally use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), never got an issue with it.

Comment: Maybe I'll move to PHPMailer in future. The pear mail package comes pre installed so I used this.